# How Can I Edit a DVD Already Burned to Disc?

Tags: video, editing, dvd, ripping, authoring

I have been asked to edit a DVD - specifically doing the following:

1. Add chapter markers
2. Add chapter selection menu
3. Combine two shorter discs into one

I would like to know if there is software that can allow me to import a DVD, make these changes, and then create a new master DVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/)** is up to the task. and it's free.

Comment: @Molly, thanks for the suggestion.  I downloaded this program and tried to use "Add title..." to import my movie.  I'm pointing to the VIDEO_TS folder, but it's not recognizing any of the files.  Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: copy the content to the hard drive and rename the extension .VOB to .MPEG

Comment: Tried these on Windows 7 but to no avail.  Going to try on XP machine when I have time...